Can not load shapefiles in QGIS 3.34.13-Prizren using MacBook Pro
I have just downloaded QGIS 3.34.13-Prizren on a MacBook Pro.
When I tried to upload shapefiles I get the prompt: ".shp is not a valid or recognized data source". I tried to upload many other shapefiles, but I always get the same prompt. I uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS for Mac many times with the same results. I am using MacOS Sequoia 15.2.
Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Interesting, I have the same machine and QGIS 3.34 (I haven't checked whether it's 3.34.13) and drag-and-dropping shapefiles do work. You could consider not using shapefiles, convert them to GeoJSON or GPKG (depending on size), and then use those. This is a nice website: http://switchfromshapefile.org/.

Unfortunately it is an already reported issue occurring on some macOS systems: see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/56721.
It should be possible to partially workaround the issue just creating a .zip archive containing the ESRI Shapefile layer's files as described at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/56721#issuecomment-2156178843.
It should also be possible to workaround the issue installing QGIS in an alternative way, e.g.:

MacPorts https://qgis.org/resources/installation-guide/#macports
Conda-forge https://aneto.pt/posts/tutorials/2019-05-29-using-qgis-from-conda/
Homebrew https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/qgis - https://osgeo.github.io/homebrew-osgeo4mac/docs/installing-QGIS-3/

